# Joomla JView::get() two parameters

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Well, i have a question and i am so confused that i decided to ask you. 
What do these statements show?

Does this display the value? (the value property of option element OR the text(JHIDE or JSHOW))?

```
$this->params->get( 'show_title');
```

And what does this statement with the two parameters indicate?

```
$this->params->get( 'show_title', 'JHIDE');
```

Could it be written in another way?

Here is the XML part of this statement:

```
<field name="show_title" type="list" default="" label="SHOW_ARTICLE_TITLE"
        description="SHOW_ARTICLE_TITLE_DESCR">
            <option value="0">JHIDE</option>
            <option value="1">JSHOW</option>
            <option value="">USE_GLOBAL</option>
</field>
```

I am very confused and i cant find the answer, even though i have printed their values with var_dump, print_r, echo etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`show_title` displays the value from the option that is selected.

`'JHIDE'` which is the second parameter, defines the default.

The default doesn't technically have to be defined but it's best to do so. It should not always be written any other way as it's a simple method that Joomla coding standards.

Comment: thank you for your response! so with the second statement the show_title takes the value "0" (the value of JHIDE)?

Comment: yes, this will take the value **0**. JHIDE is a a language string that's defined in the language file for the component

Comment: This is confusing: $this->params->get( 'show_title', 'JHIDE');
  
echo 'show title: '.$this->params->get( 'show_title'); it shows "1" again... what's going on? maybe i must define this in another place?

Comment: It shows **1** because that is the option you have selected. The second  parameter where you see ` 'JHIDE'` is where the default is defined just in case the user hasnt't set the parameter

Comment: hm i see.. i have searched internet and didn't find something helpful. thank you very much!